# C++ Error vector and classes

Tags: c++

I have an error when I try show my array could you help me please ?
**Error: expected primary-expression before '[' token|**

/*blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla*/

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Personnage.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<Personnage> tab;
    tab.push_back(Personnage("MP5", 25));
    tab.push_back(Personnage("MP7", 30));
    tab.push_back(Personnage("MP4A1", 45));
    for (int unsigned i = 0; i < tab.size(); i++)
    {
        tab[i].Attaque(tab[i + 1]);
    }
    for (int unsigned i = 0; i < tab.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << tab(Personnage[i].Show() << endl;
    }
}
```

Personnage.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Personnage.h"
using namespace std;

Personnage::Personnage(string nomArme, int degatsArme) : c_vie(100), c_arme(nomArme), c_degats(degatsArme)
{

}
Personnage::~Personnage()
{

}
void Personnage::vivant()
{
    if (c_vie > 0){
        c_death_life = "Vivant";
    } else {
        c_death_life = "Mort";
    }
}

void Personnage::RecevoirDegats(int Degats)
{
    c_vie -= Degats;
    if (c_vie < 0)
        c_vie = 0;
}

void Personnage::ChangeWeapon(string name, int Degats)
{
    c_arme = name;
    c_degats = Degats;
}

void Personnage::Attaque(Personnage &cible)
{
    cible.RecevoirDegats(c_degats);
}

void Personnage::Show()
{
    vivant();
    cout << "Vie: " << c_vie << endl;
    cout << "Arme: " << c_arme << endl;
    cout << "Degats Arme: " << c_degats << endl;
    cout << "Vie/Mort: " << c_death_life << endl << endl;
}
```

Personnage.h

```
#ifndef PERSONNAGE_H_INCLUDED
#define PERSONNAGE_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Personnage
{
public:
    Personnage();
    Personnage(std::string nomArme, int degatsArme);
    ~Personnage();
    void vivant();
    void ChangeWeapon(std::string name, int Degats);
    void RecevoirDegats(int vie);
    void Attaque(Personnage &cible);
    void Show();
protected:
    int c_vie;
    int c_degats;
    std::string c_arme;
    std::string c_death_life;
};

#endif // PERSONNAGE_H_INCLUDED
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`tab(Personnage[i].Show()` is gibberish.

You probably meant `tab[i].Show()`; and you just want to call that function, not stream its return value to `cout`, since it doesn't return anything.